# Can't connect to Frida gadget insertet to ipa file

Tags: ios, dylib, frida

I'm using non-jail-broken device
And i try to insert to ipa file Frida gadget
And then run it on the device

I use [obejction](https://github.com/sensepost/objection) to patch the ipa file

IPA file is created from my sample project - [Test Project](https://gitlab.abatutin.net/abatutin/FoodSnifferSSLPinner)

and it successfully patches the ipa and i can install it on device

but i can't connect to frida-server

```
 frida-ps -U
```

get's me

```
Failed to enumerate processes: unable to connect to remote frida-server: Unable to connect (connection refused)
```

if i integrate Frida gadget via Xcode project - it works just fine.

the only error i could get was error from device log

> AMFI: '/private/var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/2B0CF15F-BB3A-41BC-94C0-ACD1BBB49CA8/tmp/frida-sn0eph.dylib': Unrecoverable CT signature issue, bailing out.
>
> AMFI: '/private/var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/2B0CF15F-BB3A-41BC-94C0-ACD1BBB49CA8/tmp/frida-sn0eph.dylib' has no CMS blob?
>
> AMFI: code signature validation failed.

I do run app with frida gadget. And it seems the gadget waits to be connected. But i can't

Any ideas why i can't connect to frida gadget?

Answer (score 1):

to run the frida u need to use ios-deploy tool

```
ios-deploy --bundle  Payload/<app_bundleName>.app -W -d
```